# Firefox interprets margin-bottom wrong. Maybe a Bug?

Tags: css, firefox, margin

here a minimum version to reproduce the failure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .clear{clear:both;}
        .col{float:left;}
        .row{margin-bottom:30px;background-color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a Bug of Firefox or I misunderstand something.
Edit:
Forgot to explain the Problem. When im using margin-bottom for the .row in combination with a float in .col Then the  element will be dropped down for the same value as the .row margin-bottom has

Comment: Maybe you want to explain how you believe this is bugging out? As it seems to be working as expected on my end. If you describe how you expect it to perform maybe we can give you more help.

Comment: the problem is not the margin to the next element, the problem is that all the <body> element is moved 30px down. to make the failure more visible, expand the margin to 300px

Comment: i cant, i need to use margin. This is a minified version of my document and i need margin. I only cant understand why the body are dropped down

Comment: yes, you can. you can use margin-bottom and padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why Firefox is behaving differently to other browsers here. It is something to do with [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

However, you can easily fix it (no moving down in Firefox, consistency between browsers) by:

- Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.row` as an alternate way to clear the float.

You can then remove the `<div class="clear"></div>` because it's no longer required.

Comment: thx thirtydot, the overflow hidden solves the problem, but it makes it also also more confusing. I hope someone can explain why that happend.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's a Firefox bug, because no other browser I tested behaves in the same way.

Comment: we were right. It is a Bug of Firefox since 2008. [To Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's nice to know that it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine here:

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/duTgV/)

You will be wanting `padding-bottom:30px;` instead of `margin-bottom:30px;`

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/duTgV/2/ - it's some kind of Firefox weirdness to do with collapsing margins. jsFiddle's CSS reset is interfering with seeing the problem. See my answer.

Comment: it is a firefox bug, but the workaround is actually better the overflow: hidden, because you never know what depends on overflow elsewhere, but margins and padding are ALMOST one and the same

Answer (score 0):

i think you are assuming that it should pad the red row 30px on the bottom?  You want padding-bottom then.  The margin-bottom will put a 30px gap between the .row and the next element underneath it.

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonezy/VPxJH/3/) for what I mean

Answer (score 0):

there is no failure
make another div with class="row" underneath and you will see the margin-bottom:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- here is 30px space -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that the body moves, not that the margin doesnt work

Comment: Making 'ghost' DOM elements is a failure itself

Answer (score 0):

i think, the problem for him is, when you use firebug and make margin-bottom greater...then the body will go down.

If you use height then the body will not go down. Tested in FF 3.6.15

Or use padding with the margin...then the body do not move down.

Add to my comments here:

```
.row {
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: i cant use height because the content of .row and .col are dynamic

Comment: use padding with the margin-bottom

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to floated elements being removed from the normal flow and you're expecting that element to act the same. Firefox is acting as it should. Sorry I don't have time to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

**thirtydot**, you are right - this is because of collapsing margins. I was in a similar situation. However,  you can't say that it's a bug of only FireFox. In fact, in Chrome, my margins didn't used to collapse even without the float being broken. In FireFox, on the other hand, the margins collapsed for me despite broken float (whether with overflow: hidden/auto, a cleared element between, or whatever). Funnily enough, the margins where collapsing between a child and a parent, which is not supposed to happen according to W3C specs. Moreover, a positive padding fixed this issue.

As a conclusion, I can say that no browser is 100% W3C/IEEE/ISO standards-compliant. However, I don't really care which browser complies to which exact standard. What matters is that they all comply to the *same* standard. This is not happening, and I doubt it ever will.