# Pseudo-elements ignored by FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

Ladies and Gentlemen,

For quite a long time now, I've been using the following CSS technique to break float by clearing:

```
{
    display: block;
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I would then assign this set of rules to the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements (or, nowadays, seems to be `::before` and `::after`, though they're supposed to fall back to the primer). This, logically, is exactly the same thing as creating a block element either before or after the element, with `clear:both`, `overflow:hidden` and no special semantic meaning to the browser.

This allowed me to break the float without putting misleading/ambiguous and lengthy HTML elements (like `<div class="clear"></div>`) in the code, but still having my unfloated parent accomodate for all the floated children. However, this doesn't seem be working in many cases on FireFox anymore. Question: why..?

It also seems that there's no way to inspect these pseudo-elements in the sidebar to see what actually goes on.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: They've always been `::after` and `::before`, but IE doesn't support double colon so a compromise was reached unofficially of course.

Comment: Is this only in a specific version of ff?

Comment: I have also a feeling that this somehow relates to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9907340/565229)

Comment: If something's not working as you're expecting, then post a test case (http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/) that demonstrates the problem. The ["micro clearfix"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) (as suggested in an answer) works for me.

Comment: Note that :before and :after insert blocks as _kids_ of your element, not before/after the element itself.  Does that matter in your case?  It's hard to tell without a link to an actual testcase that shows your problem...

Comment: Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/36etW/

Comment: Just to make it clear. Had to do some changes to the site. Found the cause of the problem.
The rules that I posted above didn't belong to any particular class, which I used to then use on an element; instead, in the beginning of the CSS file I had a long list of selectors, which then got the style. It didn't work because I forgot to put a comma after one of the last selectors, so all the previous selectors where consequently ignored. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:"";display:table;}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;}
.clearfix{*zoom:1;}
```

It's cross-browser and works.

Example:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div style="float:left;">1</div>
   <div style="float:left;">2</div>
   <div style="float:left;">3</div>
   <div style="float:left;">4</div>
</div>
```

Added `style="float:left;"` to show they are floating, but don't use inline CSS.
No need for extra markup just to clear.

Comment: I was just going to post this, but i'm too slow:) for more info: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Didn't work, this time neither for Chrome, nor for FireFox. Ah, and by the way... thanks for the efforts, but nobody is even remotely trying to answer my question.

Comment: **Francisc**, just to clarify: do you mean to add class `clearfix` on the element itself, or on the surplus `<div>` which I mentioned..?

Comment: You add `clearfix` on the element you want to clear. As for your specific question, you need to mention the version of FireFox. Also, your clear fix will not work on browsers that do not support pseudo-elements.

Comment: The `clearfix` above works in all browsers I've ever tested and all Chrome and FireFox distributions.

Comment: Regarding your last question, you don't need to create an extra div element (extra markup) to clear the parent element. Just add it to the parent element. I'll edit the answer to include an example.

Comment: Sorry, worked now. Must have been wrong placement and incorrect use of margins. Thanks a lot.